# How to debug Neo4J stalls?

Tags: neo4j, freeze

I have a Neo4J server running that periodically stalls out for 10s of seconds. The web frontend will say it's "disconnected" with the red warning bar at the top, and a normally instant REST query in my application will apparently hang, until the stall ends and then everything returns to normal. The web frontend becomes usable and my REST query completes fine.

Is there any way to debug what is happening during one of these stall periods? Can you get a list of currently running queries? Or a list of what hosts are connected to the server? Or any kind of indication of server load?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely JVM garbage collection kicking in because you haven't allocated enough heap space.

There's a number of ways to debug this. You can for example enable GC logging (uncomment appropriate lines in neo4j-wrapper.conf), or use a profiler (e.g. YourKit) to see what's going on and why the pauses.